# Adding a custom taxonomy to "nav_menu_item"

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, navigation

Does anyone know if there is a way to handle a custom taxonomy for the `nav_menu_item` built'in post type?
When I assign my custom taxonomy to this post type, i don't see any change in the menu editor... 
It works well with `posts`, `pages` and `custom post types`.

Here how I've registered my custom taxonomy:

```
  add_action( 'init', 'my_region_taxo', 0 );
  function my_region_taxo() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Regions', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'my-text-domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Region', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'my-text-domain' ),
        (...)
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => 'region',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => false,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
        'show_in_rest'               => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'my_region_taxonomy',
        array(
            'post',
            'page',
            'nav_menu_item'
        ),
        $args
    );
  }
```

Comment: edit your question to show the code you use to define the custom taxonomy.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you enable adding your taxonomy terms to menus. To do that you just set `show_in_nav_menus` to `true` when registering the taxonomy. You have it set to `false`.

```
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true, // This
    'show_tagcloud'              => false,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
    'show_in_rest'               => true,
);

register_taxonomy(
    'my_region_taxonomy',
    array(
        'post',
        'page', // Not here
    ),
    $args
);
```

Your taxonomy should not actually be a taxonomy for the `nav_menu_item` post type.

Comment: I do't want to add my taxonomy's term in any menu, but want to manage menu items with a custom taxonomy, on the `pre_get_posts` hook for exemple

Comment: Well menu items don't have an interface for adding taxonomy terms. At all. So you'd have to build that interface. Maybe there's a better approach. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: i need to filter contents by regions, it works with assigned post types except the nav_menu_item, sInce I can't assign the terms.

Comment: I've finally found another way to handle my needs: basicaly fetching the menu items in the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` filter, and unset the one who are not targeting a post_type with the good term of my custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to use the normal post edit page by enabling `show_ui` for the `nav_menu_item` post type.

```
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'register_post_type_args', 10, 2);

function register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type === 'nav_menu_item' ) {
        $args['show_ui'] = true;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Then you can inspect the menu to get the nav_menu_item post id, and replace it in the post edit url. I know it's not as good as being able to set the terms from the menu editor, but it's a quick way to get it working.